# How to find middle element in a python linked list in a single traversal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, traversal, singly-linked-list

Sorry for asking such question(new to programming):

I want to find the middle element of linked list using **findMid** method. Sorry for poor explanation because English is not my native language. thanks :)

My code is creating the linked list and I want to find the middle element of the linked list using a single traversal. So far i've implemented one function using pointer concept by seeking help by google and that function is:

```
def findMid(self):
    slowPtr = self.__head
    fastPtr = self.__head
    if not self.__head is not None:
        while fastPtr is not None and fastPtr.next is not None:
            fastPtr = fastPtr.next.next
            slowPtr = slowPtr.next
        return slowPtr
```

but its returning me **None**

and My rest of linked list code is:

```
 class LinkedList(object):

        class Node(object):
            def __init__(self, element,next=None):
                self.element = element
                self.next = next
                # method returns address of the next Node
        def __init__(self,initial=None):
            self.__head = None
            self.__tail = None
            self.__size = 0
            if initial is not None:
                self.add(initial)

        **def findMid(self):
            slowPtr = self.__head
            fastPtr = self.__head
            if not self.__head is not None:
                while fastPtr is not None and fastPtr.next is not None:
                    fastPtr = fastPtr.next.next
                    slowPtr = slowPtr.next
                return slowPtr**



        # Return the head element in the list 
        def getFirst(self):
            if self.__size == 0:
                return None
            else:
                return self.__head.element

        # Return the last element in the list 
        def getLast(self):
            if self.__size == 0:
                return None
            else:
                return self.__tail.element

        # Add an element to the beginning of the list 
        def addFirst(self, e):
            newNode = self.Node(e) # Create a new node
            newNode.next = self.__head # link the new node with the head
            self.__head = newNode # head points to the new node
            self.__size += 1 # Increase list size

            if self.__tail == None: # the new node is the only node in list
                self.__tail = self.__head

        # Add an element to the end of the list 
        def addLast(self, e):
            newNode = self.Node(e) # Create a new node for e

            if self.__tail == None:
                self.__head = self.__tail = newNode # The only node in list
            else:
                self.__tail.next = newNode # Link the new with the last node
                self.__tail = self.__tail.next # tail now points to the last node

            self.__size += 1 # Increase size

        # Same as addLast 
        def add(self, e):
            self.addLast(e)

        # Insert a new element at the specified index in this list
        # The index of the head element is 0 
        def insert(self, index, e):
            if index == 0:
                self.addFirst(e) # Insert first
            elif index >= self.__size:
                self.addLast(e) # Insert last
            else: # Insert in the middle
                current = self.__head
                for i in range(1, index):
                    current = current.next
                temp = current.next
                current.next = self.Node(e)
                (current.next).next = temp
                self.__size += 1

        # Return true if the list is empty
        def isEmpty(self):
            return self.__size == 0

        # Return the size of the list
        def getSize(self):
            return self.__size

        def __str__(self):
            result = ""

            current = self.__head
            for i in range(self.__size):
                result += str(current.element)
                current = current.next
                if current != None:
                    result += ", " # Separate two elements with a comma
            result = re.sub('[\(\)\{\}<>]', '', result)
            return result

        # Clear the list */
        def clear(self):
            self.__head = self.__tail = None

        # Return elements via indexer
        def __getitem__(self, index):
            return self.get(index)

        # Return an iterator for a linked list
        def __iter__(self):
            return LinkedListIterator(self.__head)
class LinkedListIterator:
    def __init__(self, head):
        self.current = head

    def __next__(self):
        if self.current == None:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            element = self.current.element
            self.current = self.current.next
            return element
```

Comment: Check google before asking questions: [HERE](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-function-to-print-the-middle-of-the-linked-list/)

Comment: The middle element of a list of length N is the one at position N/2. So: count the number of list elements, then pick the one at the middle. I would do that by implementing `__len__` and `__getitem__` methods which perform these two operations and then I would simply get `the_list[len(the_list)//2]`.

Comment: @ArpitKathuria sorry bro.'ve searched alot on google but i think there's problem in my Linked List creation so that's why posted a question.

Comment: You must be more specific about what you are asking. What can your code do at the moment? What can't it do? And what are you trying to do?

Comment: If you seek help with a bug in your code you are not asking the appropriate question.  You should rewrite the question to explain what output you do get vs what output you require, asking for assistance  with that, rather than a general question about the algorithm.

Comment: sorry guys i think i'm not able to make my point clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the middle number in a *single* pass, you will need to keep a counter for the length and store the full list of elements you have seen. Then, the middle number can be find via `flattened_results[counter//2]`:

```
class Link:
  def __init__(self, head = None):
     self.head = head
     self._next = None
  def insert_node(self, _val):
     if self.head is None:
       self.head = _val
     else:
       if self._next is None:
         self._next = Link(_val)
       else:
         self._next.insert_node(_val)
  def traverse(self, count = 0):
    yield self.head
    if not self._next:
      yield [count]
    else: 
      yield from self._next.traverse(count+1)
  @classmethod
  def load_list(cls, num = 10):
     _list = cls()
     import random
     for i in range(num):
        _list.insert_node(random.choice(range(1, 20)))
     return _list

t = Link.load_list()
*l, [count] = list(t.traverse())
print(f'full list: {l}')
print('middle value:', l[count//2])
```

Output:

```
full list: [3, 18, 19, 9, 2, 2, 19, 1, 10, 10]
middle value: 2
```

Comment: Thanks <333333333333333333333333